# How to open PDF from memory using iTextsharp in Windows Application

Tags: winforms, pdf, c#-4.0, itext, windows

How do I open PDF in  browser control from memory using iTextsharp in windows application. I found this code which sends a PDF from memory as a mail [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/iTextSharp-Generate-PDF-in-Memory-and-send-as-Email-Attachment-using-C-VBNet-and-ASPNet.aspx). I need help to modify it to be able to display in a browser from memory instead of in a mail.

This is what I have done so far:

```
 private void SendPDFEmail(DataTable dt)
 {
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                sb.Append("<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td align='center' colspan = '2'><b>Certified Information Systems Auditor CISA</b><br />Notice of Mock Result<br />TESTED <b>");
                sb.Append(lblToday.Text);
                sb.Append("</b></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'><b>");
                sb.Append(lblThank.Text);
                sb.Append("</b></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2' align='center'><i><b>");
                sb.Append(lblTotalScore.Text);
                sb.Append("</b></i></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'>");
                sb.Append(lblScoreInfo.Text);
                sb.Append("</td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2' align='center'><b>");
                sb.Append(lblScoreArea.Text);
                sb.Append("</b></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("</table>");
                sb.Append("<br />");
                sb.Append("<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td align='left' colspan = '2'>Issued by</td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2' align='left'><b>Mock Team Organisers</b></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("</table>");

                StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());

                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20f, 10f, 10f, 10f);
                HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

                try
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
                        pdfDoc.Open();
                        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                        pdfDoc.Close();

                        byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                        memoryStream.Close();

                    }
                }
                catch //(Exception ex)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is a Windows application and not web application

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Do *NOT* follow that example. It uses `HTMLWorker`, which is years obsolete. Whoever wrote that code, should either take it offline, or replace it with `XMLWorker` (iText 5) or preferably pdfHTML (iText 7).

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Thank you for pointing that out. Some codes will help.

Comment: @FuSsA I have edited my question